# multidimensional array in angular with *ngFor

Tags: angular

I have a multidimensional array in angular

**html**

```
<table>
    <tr  *ngFor="let x of multi">
        <td>{{x}}</td>
        <td>{{x}}</td>
        <td>{{x}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**ts** edit* - you dont need the for i use

basically you only need to declare the array

( multi:Number[][] = [[1,2,3],[21,22,23], [31,32,33]]; )

```
multi:Number[][] = [[1,2,3],[21,22,23], [31,32,33]];

  

  ngOnInit(): void {
  
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      
      for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        
        this.multi[[i][j]];

        console.log(this.multi[i][j]);
      }
      
    }
  }
```

well my outcome isn´t exatly want i wanted

```
1,2,3       1,2,3       1,2,3
21,22,23    21,22,23    21,22,23
31,32,33    31,32,33    31,32,33
```

this is want i was trying to get

```
1   2   3
21  22  23
31  32  33
```

thx for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not iterating over the second dimension. Try this:

```html
<table>
    <tr *ngFor="let y of multi">
        <td *ngFor="let x of y">{{x}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```